# Animation of a view's subview hiding behind another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

Im trying to animate a `UIImage` which is a subview of a `UIView` in the interface builder.
My problem is, that this animation goes "through" another view which is the table view and then it simply "goes behind" it and doesn't show all the way.
My view hierarchy is like this:

```
View
   View
      SubviewToAnimate
   TableView
```

I have tried `[self.view bringViewToFront:SubviewToAnimate]`
Both in the view itself, and in the animation.

Code for animation:

```
-(void)startAnimationWithImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView{

    imageViewToMove = imageView;
    imageViewFirstAlpha = imageViewToMove.alpha;

    firstCenterOfView = imageViewToMove.center;

    double firstX =self.parabelWidth*self.startValue;
    double firstY = self.parabelHeight*pow(self.startValue, 2);
    firstPointOfParabel = CGPointMake(firstX, firstY);

    if (points) {
        points = nil;
    }
    points =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int counter = self.startValue; counter < self.stopValue; counter++) {

        double y = self.parabelHeight*pow(counter, 2);
        double x = self.parabelWidth*counter;

        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y);
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
        //DLog(@"point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));

    }

    animationCounter = 0;
    [self moveView];


}

-(void)moveView{

    if (animationCounter < points.count) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:self.duration
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                         animations:^{

                             NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:animationCounter];
                             CGPoint point = [val CGPointValue];

                             double delta = 1.0/points.count;
                             imageViewToMove.center = CGPointMake(firstCenterOfView.x-firstPointOfParabel.x+point.x, firstCenterOfView.y-firstPointOfParabel.y+point.y);
                             imageViewToMove.alpha = sqrt(imageViewToMove.alpha-delta);

                             double scale = animationCounter*delta;
                             imageViewToMove.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sqrt(1-scale), sqrt(1-scale));

                             animationCounter++;

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             [self moveView];

                         }];
    }else if (animationCounter == points.count) {
        imageViewToMove.center = firstCenterOfView;
        imageViewToMove.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{

                             imageViewToMove.alpha = imageViewFirstAlpha;

                         }
                         completion:NULL];
    }else
        return;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `[self.view bringViewToFront:SubviewToAnimate]` to put your image view on top of the table view because it isn't a sibling of the table view.

If you had...

```
View
    SubView
    ImageView (animated view)
    TableView
```

Then that code would work.

Or, in your current hierarchy, you could bring the SubView to the front which would bring the image view with it.

Comment: Brought the Subview to front, worked like a charm! thank you. (will accept answer in 5 minutes)